# Set nested links with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a question about the React Router.

Now, I have a webpage with that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there is another link on the page called "Custom Hooks".If I click on it, it will be shown something like this:
[image]

What I want now is to go to the a new page which the link shown in the image above, where the page will only shown me the "Example" and not the "This is UseState function" text.

In my code:

[image]

With my code, it cannot performs the route that I want to.

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Neither the `h1` nor `div` with example text are rendered into a route so they will always be rendered. Please also post code as formatted code snippets instead of images; images are more difficult to read and they aren't searchable.

Comment: Hi Drew, I tried the method take out the h1 and div from the Routes but is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you seem to have misunderstood how the Switch component works. Think of it as a way of selecting what component to render based on the url. In the above code snippet,

```
<Link to="/Homepage"><Button>Back to Homepage</Button></Link>
<h1>This is UseState Function</h1>
<div>Example</div><Link to="/UseStatePage/UseStateFunction">Custom Hooks</Link>
```

is not under , meaning that whenever UseStateWebpage component is rendered, the Link, h1 and div with 'This is UseState Function' **will always be rendered**. If you want it to be rendered optionally based on the URL, there are multiple ways to achieve it. One way is as follows.

```
<Router>
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/UseStatePage" exact render={
          ()=>{
                  return(
                            <React.Fragment>
                               <Link to="/Homepage"><Button>Back to Homepage</Button></Link>
                               <h1>This is UseState Function</h1>
                               <div>Example</div><Link to="/UseStatePage/UseStateFunction">Custom Hooks</Link>
                            <React.Fragment>
                        )
              }
      }/>
   </Switch>
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/UseStatePage/UseStateFunction" exact component={UseStateFunction}/>
   <Switch>
<Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither the `h1` nor `div` with example text are rendered into a route so they will always be rendered. Render the "homepage" content into its own route, something like the following.

```
function useStateWebPage() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Link to="/Homepage">Back To Homepage</Link>

      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/UseStatePage/UseStateFunction"
          component={UseStateFunction}
        />
        <Route path="/Homepage>
          <h1>This is UseState function</h1>
          <div>
            Example
            <Link to="/UseStatePage/UseStateFunction">custom Hooks</Link>
          </div>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```